# replace first occurrence find by line on Terminal Mac

Tags: macos, replace

I need to use lot of data (Biology) and prefer work on the terminal of my mac. 
Someone could say me how can we replace just the first space by an other caracter like an - ?? 
I want to paste the two name of genes ... Thanks

> NAMEOFGENE SECONDNAME CGAGCGTCTCTCTACGTTAGAGTTACTCCTCTCGCGAGAACGTATCTCCCCTTCCTCAAT GGGCTCGTGCTTGAGTAAGTCCATAGGGTGGTAGGCCGGGTGCTGGGGCGGCAGCTGATG CTGGGTGAGGTGGTAGTGATGATGAGCCGACGGCATGCCAACCTGAGGTCTTATCGTGCC

Answer (score 0):

Try with Sed:

```
sed 's/FindThisWord/ReplaceWithThisWord/g' file.txt
```

http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_find_and_replace_using_sed

Comment: There is space into the DNA sequences (CAAT GGG etc) and with this command I replace all the spaces ... and there is the main problem!
Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe an example file would help. BTW, removing the global `g` flag from the above command, it *should* match only the first occurence.